# How can noise be used in physics simulations?

Tags: simulations, chaos-theory, noise

I have been studying chaotic dynamical systems and noise. What is the difference between chaos and noise?
I have looked over the internet for a good definition of what [noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_%28disambiguation%29) is but I haven't managed to find one. What is noise is and how it can be used in physics simulations?

Comment: I often have music playing in the lab - does that count? As it stands, your question is unclear and not specific - what exactly are you interested in, and how does it link to physics simulations?

Comment: This question is very broad. Surely you have read several definitions of noise, such as the one in the link that QMechanic has edited into the post. Please explain what about the definition you do not understand, etc. Also, asking for both a general discussion of noise and a complete list of how it's used in simulations is waaaay to much. Narrow down the question, please.

Comment: It has to do with dynamical systems and systems that behave chaotically

Answer (score 3):

"What is noise and how can it be used in physics simulations" could fill a large volume (or more).

But let me give you a simple example. In nature there are many stochastic processes - where events occur "with a certain probability". An example is radioactive decay. If you want to model the properties of radiation emitted by a radioactive source surrounded by a scattering medium, the number of possible ways in which radiation could be emitted and scattered would very quickly become too large to compute.

This is where a technique called "Monte Carlo Simulation" comes to the rescue. It is named after the city-state of Monte Carlo, famous for its casino. In a MC simulation, you generate a finite number of "possible events", in essence by "rolling the dice" at any point where you might have multiple outcomes with different probabilities. "In the next millisecond, do I have a decay?" `<rolls dice>` "ah I rolled a 6. So yes.". "when I hit this voxel of matter, do I interact?" `<rolls dice>` "oh, a 2. So no." Repeat for the next, and the next...

After a few million such simulations, you have a pretty good idea of the probability that radiation ends up in a certain area, and what the energy distribution is. The longer you keep going, the more accurate your estimate - even if it is never exact.

Is this using noise? Indirectly, yes - because the randomness of the events (different probabilities) means that any measurement will be different from the one before it, or the one after. That is a form of noise.

Comment: thank you for you example. That is what I was looking for. So basically noise = randomness?

Comment: Well - noise is "anything that is not the thing you wanted to measure". It is not simple - which is why I said "could fill a volume".

Comment: My answer does not deal with chaotic systems, by the way. You added that comment after I started writing my answer.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. When you say "scattering medium" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Any object with electrons in it will scatter radiation (gamma rays) according to Compton's equation, with probabilities (as a function of energy and angle) that are described by the Klein-Nishina equation. Unlike absorption of radiation (for example by lead), scatter results in a transfer of some energy to the medium (for example, water) and the scattering of the radiation in a new direction. What that new direction is is not deterministically defined - it is stochastic. Like when you hit the break in pool - you shoot the cue ball, and balls fly all over the table.